# 301 redirect with exceptions

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have the following htaccess settings and my purpose is that bacchusbreak.com and www.bacchusbreak.com should redirect to my shopify website, except the faq folder.

bacchusbreak.com/faq works, but, www.bacchusbreak.com/faq gives 404.
Any thoughts? :)

```
RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^bacchusbreak\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.bacchusbreak\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/faq/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/wholesailors\.myshopify\.com\ \/" [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteEngine on
# Combine the original two lines into one line, making "www." optional
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?bacchusbreak\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/faq/
# No quotes needed around the destination URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://wholesailors.myshopify.com [R=301,L]
```